# Multi-language URLs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For a "welcome" page in my Laravel application, I need to have a route for 4 different languages. Currently I have made it like this:

```
# German
Route::get('/willkommen', 'WaitingListController@index')->name('waiting_list.index');

# French
Route::get('/bienvenu', 'WaitingListController@index')->name('waiting_list.index');

# Italian
Route::get('/benvenuto', 'WaitingListController@index')->name('waiting_list.index');

# Spanish
Route::get('/bienvenidos', 'WaitingListController@index')->name('waiting_list.index');
```

This is fine for one page I suppose, but I will need to translate URLs for every page on the site eventually. This becomes cumbersome, as I would have to make any future change 4 times. That's clearly something to avoid.

So my question is: what is the best way to do this? I would prefer not to have to create 4 routes for each page in `routes/web.php`. Is there a more elegant solution? Can I somehow pass an array to the route instead of a string perhaps?

Comment: Why not use Laravel's build in localisation techniques? You would have one route and a param to manage locale. For eg: `welcome/{locale}` or `{locale}/welcome` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization#configuring-the-locale  OR is it important for the route to be in the chosen language as well?

Comment: The client wants the URL itself to be in the chosen language...so I need "/willkommen" for German, not something like "/de/welcome".

Comment: I see. Just a thought, maybe look into using a regex. `Route::get('regexToMatchTheFourLangRoutes, 'WaitingListController@index')->name('waiting_list.index');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, something like this could work

```
Route::get('/{welcome}', 'WaitingListController@index')
->where('welcome', 'willkommen|bienvenu|bienvenidos')
->name('waiting_list.index');
```